# Does Clojure have a function similar to BinCounts in Mathematica?

Tags: clojure

In the function BinCounts you input a vector (list in Mathematica), a minimum, maximum and width size. The function counts the number of elements in successive bins of specified width within the interval minimum to maximum.

An example input would be 
([1 3 2 1 4 5 6 2] 0 10 1) where 0 corresponds to the minimum, 10 is the maximum and 1 is the bin width.

The function would then output 
[0 2 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]

This brings another question to mind as in Mathematica infinity is a valid input for the minimum or maximum (disregarding sign). Does Clojure handle such an input when specifying the interval?

Another example where the interval is not given
([1 3 2 1 4 5 6 2] 2) where 2 is bin width

outputs [2 3 2 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure does not have this function built in, though it's fairly straightforward to write:

```
user> (defn bin-counts [data min max width] 
        (for [bucket (range min max)] 
          (count (filter #(<= bucket % (+ width bucket)) data))))
#'user/bin-counts

user> (bin-counts [1 3 2 1 4 5 6 2] 0 10 1)
(2 4 3 2 2 2 1 0 0 0)

user> (bin-counts [1 3 2 1 4 5 6 2] 0 10 0)
(0 2 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0)
```

A more complete version would supply default values for min max etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution makes just one pass through the `data`.

```
(defn bin-counts [data min max width]
  (let [buckets (->> data
                   (filter #(and (<= min %) (< % max))) ; in range
                   (map #(quot (- % min) width))) ; convert to bucket number
        bucket-count (quot (- max min) width)]
    (reduce
     #(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2)))
     (vec (repeat bucket-count 0))
     buckets)))
```

- `buckets` is a lazy sequence of the valid bucket numbers.
- The `reduce` increments the counts (initially zero) for every such
  occurrence.

---

As for infinity, Clojure inherits `Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY` from Java. These behave as you would expect with `<` and the like. For example, you can use them as end points for the [`range`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/range#source) function.

```
user=> (take 10 (range 0 Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY -1))
(0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9)
```

In fact, `range` uses `Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY` as its default end point.